# Angular 16 upgrade is not supporting angular-custom-modal

Tags: angular16

My project is upgrading from ng 15 to ng 16.
For modal creation, we are using angular-custom-modal package but it is not supported by angular 16 .

Could you please suggest any work around or the best alternative without requiring  much efforts as it is widely used in the application.

I have tried to use mat dialog . As I mentioned,angular-custom-modal is widely used in the application . So, changing it become a tedious task.